# Compile EXE for 64 and 32 bits - CodeBlocks MinGW

Tags: mingw, codeblocks

In codeblocks I only can execute the exe on x64 bits computers.
How can I compile for 32 and 64 bits. Im using MinGW64.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't depend on Code::Blocks, but the compiler you're using.

MinGW-w64 exists in both a 32-bit and 64-bit Windows versions.

You can download standalone builds of MinGW-w64 from http://winlibs.com/ for both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows, and the site also explains how to configure them in Code::Blocks.